# error in wordpress theme (formatting.php)

Tags: php, wordpress

when i open my web site in homepage i see only header and this error :

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted
>   to string in /home/mahooorc/public_html/wp-includes/formatting.php on
>   line 3275

this problem is just on my homepage and other links are ok. i disabled all plugins but it doesn't answer! line 3275 is

```
$url = preg_replace('|[^a-z0-9-~+_.?#=!&;,/:%@$\|*\'()\\x80-\\xff]|i', '', $url);

    function esc_url( $url, $protocols = null, $_context = 'display' ) {
    $original_url = $url;
    if ( '' == $url )
        return $url;
    $url = preg_replace('|[^a-z0-9-~+_.?#=!&;,/:%@$\|*\'()\\x80-\\xff]|i', '', $url);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is usually caused by missing taxonomies that are used in a menu, but do not exist anymore.

You have a couple of solutions to try, but do not forget to always create a backup of your files and database before you try any of them.

**Method 1**

1. Remove the taxonomy items from the menu
2. Delete all session data, cookies etc...

**Method 2**

1. Find the table `wp_term_taxonomy` in the database
2. Find a record called `nav_menu`
3. Delete that record

**Method 3**

1. Find the table `wp_terms` in the database
2. Look at the different terms and decide which ones you do not need
3. Delete the terms you do not need anymore

When none of these solutions, or a combination of the solutions work, please let me know. You have still a couple more options, but those are a lot more destructive.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of receiving the expected $url as as string, the esc_url() function receive a WP_Error object.

Try to add this code before the faulty line to learn more about the error:
    echo $url->get_error_message();
It will display the error message which can help you understand where it comes from.

Remember to remove this added line after that.

People having the same issue are often talking about encoding problems. Are you using special encoding ?

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function get_error_message() on a non-object in /home/mahooorc/public_html/wp-includes/formatting.php on line 3275

Comment: my bad, this function must be called more than once and only crash once. try this: if (is_wp_error( $url)) echo $url->get_error_message();

Comment: It does not matter to me, but you are changing core files. Any update of Wordpress will create the same error message again. I would strongly advice to solve the problem in the application itself, and not by changing core files

Comment: @AgeDeO... What I wrote is a debug advice, not a fix... Please notice the line which says : _Remember to remove this added line after that._

Comment: @Bar-code Then this should be a comment, because it is not an answer to the question